# Dynamic select and filter in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm a beginner to Rails and I've been struggling to create a filter feature, I've done some googling but I feel like I'm in a bottleneck situation right now, would really need some help.

---

**Mock up:**

[image]

[image]

I have an Event model, with title, description etc, and now I want to add Court, House and Event type into the model. When a user create an event, they must choose a court, a house and what type of event it is.

- User must choose a court then select a house, as each house name is different in each court.
- Preferably the house dropdown should only appear after court value is selected.

The most important part is the users can filter their search later on, and get a list of events based on the selections they've made.

```
/events?court=foo&house=bar&event_type=fun
```

And it's ok if the user only choose one choice and clicked Search

```
/events?court=foo     # show all foo court events
/events?court=foo&event_type=fun     # show all fun type events at foo court
```

---

**My Questions**

From some answers I've seen, some people have created seperate models for Court, House etc. Is that necessary in this case? I'd like to keep it all in Event.rb, so I can do

```
validates :court, :house, :event_type, presence: true
```

For the View, we would also need JavaScript right? Do we use it along side with a Event method like this?

```
def return_house(selected_court)
    if selected_court == 'foo'
      ['bar1', 'bar2', 'bar3']
    elsif selected_court == 'baz'
      ['qux1', 'qux2', 'qux3']
    end
end
```

I've been using f.input for dropdown selections, but I've seen people use f.collection_select?

Answer (score 0):

Because a court can be associated with multiple events, you'll need to create separate models and use a one_to_many relationship.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :court, through: :event_court
end

class EventCourt < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :court
end

class Court < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_courts
  has_many :events, through: :event_court
end
```

You'll also want to do a similar thing for event_type.

This type of setup is why you see other people using collection_select.

I assume a court can also have multiple houses, so you'll want to create a has_many relationship between courts and houses

```
class Court < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :houses
end

class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :court
end
```

Note: This is not functional. Do not just copy paste it. Instead, read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

I assume you are not just new to Rails, but also web dev. If that is the case, you might be in over your head. You are doing some fairly advanced Rails stuff.

Comment: Thanks for helping out, I've thought using multiple models, but then how do I filter/search between them? I found this gem https://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope but It seems only use controllers not models

Comment: That gem uses models. The first code example they give is a model. That gem helps your controller and your model talk. I think you should probably try creating a simpler application first, e.g., a blog.